# NotFoundHttpException en laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, post

i'm using laravel 5.2 and i'm trying to define routes, but i don't know why i get  NotFoundHttpException when i try to do post.

```
<form action="POST" action="post_to_me">
    <input type="text" name="name" >
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

this is my form, very simple.

```
route::post('post_to_me',function(){
    echo "post";
});
```

here i define the route to post, but when i run tha app, NotFoundHttpException comes out. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Please write in english

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ ready

Comment: Try adding a slash before the uri `action="/post_to_me"` or use the url() helper `action="{{ url('post_to_me') }}"`

Comment: thank you, but I still get the error

Comment: i already  solved it, i wrote action="POST" instead of method="POST"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have missed adding the CSRF Token to your form. Try adding

```
    // Vanilla PHP
<?php echo csrf_field(); ?>
```

or

```
// Blade Template Syntax
    {{ csrf_field() }}
```

just below your form tag

Comment: You have set action="POST" where it should be method="POST"

Comment: ooo sh*t. It's true, now run it. thank you. Maybe it would be good if you edit your answer with this solution.

Comment: Also, by default Laravel doesn't accept POST Requests if CSRF is missing